# i want want to perform looped serial database insertion in mongodb on node js by bluebird promises,but unable to do so

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bluebird

using for loop i want to insert data by mongoose promises and handle output one by one

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (xyz) {
        return Service.registerInterestsAsync(registerTruckArray)
            .then(function(x) {
                passoutputinArray(x)
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used bluebird but you can do this by writing your own recursive function.

```
var handleResponse = function(err, data) {
    //perform action
}

function inserIntoMongo(dataArray, counter) {
  if( counter < dataArray.length) {
      mongoose.InsertDocument(dataArray[counter], function(err, data) {
          handleResponse(err, data);
          counter = counter + 1;
          insertIntoMongo(dataArray, counter);
      }
  }
}
```